# Writing byte array to an existing zip file using java

Tags: java, file, filesystems, zip, nio

Hi I am trying to write a program to read blocks of bytes from an input file (based on offset and lengths) - store them in a byte array as I am reading it.

For every block I need to call the method below to create a file directly inside the zip file - contents of this file will be the whats there in the byte array.

Here is my method -

```
public void addBytesToZip(String zipPath, byte[] contentBytes, String outputFileName) throws Exception
    {
        if (zipfs == null){         
            zipfs = createZipFileSystem(zipPath);
        }

        Path zipFilePath = zipfs.getPath(outputFileName);

        Files.write(zipFilePath, contentBytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);

    }
```

the createZipFileSystem method is succesfully creating an empty zip file in the location that I am specifying. I am using FileSystems.newFileSystem to do that.

The byte array has the correct contents inside this method - when i write it to a file outside the zip it works.

Only step that is not working is the Files.write(zipFilePath, contentBytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW); line

The values I am passing to this method is -

String zipPath = "C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/ZippingUtilOutput/packge.zip";   ---- this is the path to the zip file

String outputFileName = "/file1.tiff"; --- this is the name of the file to be created inside the zip with the contents of the byte array (contentBytes)

there is no exception thrown. The output of the write method is just "/file1.tiff"

Hope someone could help me with this, it will be much appreciated!

Comment: `Files.write(zipFilePath, imageBytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);` what is imageBytes?

Comment: sorry corrected that. was a typo when i was forming the question here. The code still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I had not closed the FileSystem after the write statement!

added zipfs.close();